# Tagging Photo from outside facebook and making it appear like a normal "Within Facebook" tagging

Tags: facebook, photos

I have found the face.com app that seems to allow facebook tagging from outside websites. This seems to work brilliantly except the way it connects to facebook. It just sends a link to the tagged persons facebook wall linking it.

What I am looking for is to tag someone on my website using the face.com app (or any other app that does the job) and this then shows up as a normal tagging in that persons photos, they same as if they had been tagged within facebook.

I have spoken to developers at face.com and they confirmed this is certainly possible but the way it is displayed is to do with facebooks api and not theirs.

Ive done a search but cant find any questions asking for the same thing, can anyone help?

Regards
Tom

Comment: Ok so when it appears in a persons photos the tag must be linked to a photo that is in facebooks database of photos? Once the photo has been sent to facebook can it not be stored in their database somewhere to allow the photo to just show up in the users photos? I basically want to store the photos on my website(to draw traffic there) rather than say add them to a facebook group and just let people tag from there!

Answer (score 0):

If it's not in facebook's database, it won't appear as tagged on facebook.

One way to do that would be to upload the picture to the user's facebook pictures, and tag it using the API.
This way, the picture would on on facebook, and the tag would be registered on facebook.

This is the only way because photo tags are associated to a Photo ID, not a photo URL.
(tags are linked to PID, which is linked to URL in another table, but this URL must be on facebook's server)

Answer (score 0):

This is very unlikely to happen because FB does not have control over photos off the Facebook servers.  This means that tagging can be abused/broken very easily.  For example, if you tag someone in a photo on "someserver.com" and then someserver takes a very long time to load, then it looks like Facebook is slow when they try to show you the photo.  But even worse, if someserver is down, or if the photo is moved/removed, and then FB looks broken.

But finally, consider that you could tag someone in a regular photo, and once they've accepted the tag, the photo could be changed to anything you want - something offensive, advertising, and so forth, and FB wouldn't know about it.

So don't expect FB to implement this anytime soon.